# Count capitalized of each sentence in a paragraph Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, split, capitalize

I answered my own question. Forgot to initialize `count = 0`

I have a bunch of sentences in a paragraph.

1. `a = "Hello there. this is the best class. but does not offer anything."` as an example.
2. To figure out if the first letter is capitalized, my thought is to `.split` the string so that `a_sentence = a.split(".")`
3. I know I can `"hello world".capitalize!` so that if it was `nil` it means to me that it was already capitalized
   EDIT
4. Now I can use array method to go through value and use '`.capitalize!`
5. And I know I can check if something is `.strip.capitalize!.nil?`

But I can't seem to output how many were capitalized.

EDIT

```
 a_sentence.each do |sentence|
        if (sentence.strip.capitalize!.nil?)
            count += 1
            puts "#{count} capitalized"
        end
    end
```

It outputs:

```
1 capitalized
```

Thanks for all your help. I'll stick with the above code I can understand within the framework I only know in Ruby. :)

Comment: You're getting this error because you need to define `count` first. Try adding `count = 0` before using `count += 1`, outside the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
b = []
a.split(".").each do |sentence|
  b << sentence.strip.capitalize
end
b = b.join(". ") + "."
#  => "Hello there. This is the best class. But does not offer anything."
```

Answer (score 1):

Your post's title is misleading because from your code, it seems that you want to get the count of capitalized letters at the beginning of a sentence.

Assuming that every sentence is finishing on a period (a full stop) followed by a space, the following should work for you:

```
split_str = ". "
regex = /^[A-Z]/

paragraph_text.split(split_str).count do |sentence|
  regex.match(sentence)
end
```

And if you want to simply ensure that each starting letter is capitalized, you could try the following:

```
paragraph_text.split(split_str).map(&:capitalize).join(split_str) + split_str
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to split the string into sentences:

```
str = "It was the best of times. sound familiar? Out, damn spot! oh, my." 

str.scan(/(?:^|[.!?]\s)\s*\K[A-Z]/).length
  #=> 2
```

The regex could be written with documentation by adding `x` after the closing `/`:

```
r = /
     (?:        # start a non-capture group
      ^|[.!?]\s # match ^ or (|) any of ([]) ., ! or ?, then one whitespace char
      )         # end non-capture group
      \s*       # match any number of whitespace chars
      \K        # forget the preceding match
      [A-Z]     # match one capital letter
    /x

a = str.scan(r)
  #=> ["I", "O"]  
a.length
  #=> 2
```

Instead of [Array#length](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-length), you could use its alias, `size`, or [Array#count](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-count).

Answer (score 0):

You can count how many were capitalized, like this:

```
a = "Hello there. this is the best class. but does not offer anything."
a_sentence = a.split(".")

a_sentence.inject(0) { |sum, s| s.strip!; s.capitalize!.nil? ? sum += 1 : sum }
# => 1 

a_sentence
# => ["Hello there", "This is the best class", "But does not offer anything"]
```

And then put it back together, like this:

```
"#{a_sentence.join('. ')}."
#  => "Hello there. This is the best class. But does not offer anything."
```

**EDIT**

As @Humza sugested, you could use `count`:

```
a_sentence.count { |s| s.strip!; s.capitalize!.nil? }
# => 1
```

Comment: Take a look at my response. You can simply pass a block to `count` and make things a lot easier.

Comment: @victorkohl yes I like a_sentence.count { |s| s.strip!; s.capitalize!.nil? } better  :) thanks!